# how to access coordinates of a event

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I want to make my popup blinked over the event in the full calendar .whenever mouse is over the event. So I need do read the coordinates of the event which is clicked.

And how to fix any `<div></div>`  at that coordinates.
in my full callendar code is for mouse over,

```
eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
     $("#descriptionbox").html(event.title  +"        " +"C-ordinates::" ).show();
},
eventMouseout: function (event, jsEvent, view) { 
    $("#descriptionbox").hide(); 
},
```

And  for div that is to be shown  near the clicked events coordinat.

```
 <div id="descriptionbox" style="position:absolute; border-radius:5%; margin-left:1%; color:white; margin-top:2%; z-index:100; background-color:dodgerblue;padding:1%">Description</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the coordinates from the jsEvent parameter.

You can read it from the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventMouseover):

> jsEvent holds the native JavaScript event with low-level information
>   such as mouse coordinates.

Comment: i have another problem to access a variable under the java script from the rajor view(MVC). both are in same view page.

Comment: Hi @vimalraturi. As I thought that is a new question out of the scope of this one, I suggest you to try to found the answer on the community or create a new question.

Comment: ok...actually.there is a 90 min limit ..for next question...thanks

Comment: Consider upvoting or accepting my answer if it was usefull/correct.